# Flutter Why my widget having second color on border?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a widget as a badge. But When I want to add a white border on it I don't know why it's having another color too. I assume it's coming from the stack. But how can I fix it? To make it clear :

[image]

I don't want that blue outline on my border.

My Widget :

```
Stack(
                                children: [
                                  CircleNotification(
                                    backgroundColor: ColorService.purpleHalfOpacityBackground,
                                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      AssetService.boldChatBubbleIcon,
                                    ),
                                    radius: 32,
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 30,
                                    top: 25,
                                    child: Stack(children: [
                                      Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                                        ),
                                    
                                        child: CircleNotification(
                                          backgroundColor: ColorService.halfOpacityBlue,
                                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                            AssetService.cameraSvg,
                                          ),
                                          radius: 32,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                         //When i add that border its coming with outline
                                    -->        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                                            color: ColorService.blueTitleColor,
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          ),
                                          child: const Text("1",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        right: 0,
                                        top: 0,
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```

Comment: You want to remove blue border on your badge?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes I want to make it white border only.

Comment: Can you remove the line under border which is color: ColorService.blueTitleColor, and I suggest you to use https://pub.dev/packages/badges package, it needs less coding and works great.

Comment: @BurakAybi thanks for reply. I was using badges and it has same problem thats why i tried make myself and its same result. And when i remove color:ColorService.blueTitleColor its simply deleting color of my container so its being transparent that time. When i make it Colors.red or something else that outline being red or i choosed color too i dont want that outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a bug in flutter, see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13675).

What you can do is wrap your container with another one that has your border color as a background **and** border color:

```dart
child: DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
    color: Colors.white,  // <- The background is the same color as the border.
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(  // <- You don't need any border here.
      color: ColorService.blueTitleColor,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    child: // ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks for answer man i didn't know that bug lol first time saw it :) Thanks for reply its worked on me!